# k way merge sort divide and conquer

Tags: python-3.x

```
from math import ceil
def merge(all_lst):
    sorted_lst = []
    while all_lst:
        min_value,index = all_lst[0][0],0
        for lst in all_lst:
            if lst[0]<min_value:
                min_value = lst[0]
                index = all_lst.index(lst)
        sorted_lst.append(min_value)
        all_lst[index].pop(0)
        if not all_lst[index]:
            all_lst.remove(all_lst[index])     
    return sorted_lst


def merge_sort(lst, k):
    def split(lst):
        split_lst = []
        j = ceil(len(lst)/k) if len(lst)>=k else 1
        for i in range(0,len(lst),j):
            split_lst.append(lst[i:i+j])
        return split_lst
    lst=split(lst)
    if len(lst[0])==1:
        return lst
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            lst[i]=merge(merge_sort(lst[i],k))
        return merge(lst)
```

Above is my code for k-way merge sort. Basically what it does is split the list into k smaller list by calling the **split** function until each sublist in the list is a single element. Then the list containing sublists will be merged into one single list.

My code works fine when splitting is done twice. (eg.[3,6,8,5,2,1,4,7] -> [3,6,8],[5,2,1],[4,7] -> [3],[6],[8],[5],[2],[1],[4],[7]). But when the splitting is done more than twice, (eg,[3,6,8,5,2,1,4,7] -> [3,6,8,5],[2,1,4,7]  -> [3,6],[8,5],[2,1],[4,7] -> [3],[6],[8],[5],[2],[1],[4],[7]), the code will fail. Can anyone help find me find out what goes wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having is that `merge_sort` sometimes returns a flattened list and other times returns a list of lists. You should probably return a flat list in all cases. There's some other cruft: You don't need `split` to be its own function, since you only call it the one time.

Here's a greatly simplified version of your code:

```
def merge_sort(lst, k):
    if len(lst) == 1: # simpler base case
        return lst

    j = ceil(len(lst)/k) # no need to check for k < len(lst) (ceil handles it)

    #split and recursively sort in one step
    lst = [merge_sort(lst[i:i+j], k) for i in range(0, len(lst), j)]

    return merge(lst) # always return a merged list (never a list of lists)
```

Comment: @Blocknght your j becomes 0 pretty fast, during the iteration.

Comment: @oba2311: I don't see any way `j` can become `0` in this code. It should always be at least `1`, unless you pass in an empty list at the start (it will never recurse on an empty list itself). If you want it to be able to handle empty lists passed in by some outside caller, just change the `if len(lst) == 1` code to use `<=` instead of `==`.